# Google Places api giving OVER QUERY LIMIT

Tags: ios, google-maps-api-3, uitableview

I am developing an application in iPhone in which I am showing the list of places in tableview.

I want to show the distance of the place from user's current location in cell.  To find the distance, I am using Google api and I had written the code to find the distance in the cell itself.

There are 20 rows in the tableview so the Google web service is called 20 times and thats why it's giving OVER QUERY LIMIT response.

To overcome this, I have also used `NSOperationQueue` but this is also not working.  The Google api is still giving the OVER QUERY LIMIT response.

Does anyone have an idea about how to overcome this?

Comment: you should request a google maps API key

Comment: Actually the url to find the distance doesn't require the api key here is the url http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=%f,%f&destination=%f,%f&sensor=false&mode=driving where %f,%f is latitude and longitude

Comment: You should definitely be using an API key.

Answer (score 2):

don't use Google API to calculate the distance. Instead of Google use the CLLocation of iOS.

Take a look at [CLLocation Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html), and use:

```
- (CLLocationDistance)distanceFromLocation:(const CLLocation *)location
```

Comment: actually the problem with the CLLocation is ,it's not giving the actual distance through route,it just draw the line between two places and returns the distance.

Comment: Which Google API are you using?

Comment: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=%f,%f&destination=%f,%f&sensor=false&mode=driving where %f,%f is latidude and longitude.

Comment: Just one idea, try to use sleep(0.5f) between each request.... Just adjust the time

Answer (score 0):

Google Places API has a limit on the number of requests you can make per day ([more here](https://developers.google.com/places/policies#usage_limits)). So adding delays between calls will not really help.

If you have the lat/lon of both the points, you can use the [Haversine Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) to calculate the distance or use Core Location.

Comment: Actually, in addition to there being a daily quota, there are also rate limits.